# Set cookie domain

Tags: javascript, cookies

I need to set the domain for a cookie in javascript.

I've tried doing it like this:

```
<script>
function checkCookieChange() {
Cookies.set('storelocationChange', 'true','/' ,'.testsite.co.uk', {expires: 7});
};
</script>
```

But it's not setting the domain. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create and read a value from cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie)

Comment: Where are you executing this script? Meaning, what was the document this code is executed in loaded from …?

Comment: Are you setting the domain to one that is valid for the URL that the page was loaded from?

Comment: What is `Cookies.set`? That isn't a browser built-in. Tell us which library you are using.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you code looks as if you are using https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie.
if that's the case, this would work:

```
Cookies.set('storelocationChange', 'true', { expires: 1, domain: 'domain.com' });
```

Comment: There are a lot of cookie libraries that have syntax like that.